# GSA: How to obtain ASR (Advanced Search Report) by using Administrative API

Tags: google-search-appliance

My organization is using gsa version 7.2

Is it possible to get ASR (Advanced Search Report) by using Administrative API? I referred to a document entitled, “Administrative API Developer’s Guide: Protocol”, nothing is mentioned about that. Is there any other method which allows me to obtain automatically by script?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to obtain Advanced Search Reports using the Administrative API. You have to download them from the Admin Console, either by hand or by screen scraping.

For an *unsupported* example of screen scraping the Admin Console, you can look at [gsa_admin.py](https://github.com/google/gsa-admin-toolkit/blob/master/gsa_admin.py) in the GSA Admin Toolkit. I don't think this includes code to scrape ASR logs, but it should point you in the right direction if you want to try.

Comment: Will's right, it's not part of the API but you can extend the gdata api code to add the file download.
https://code.google.com/p/google-enterprise-gdata-api/